# Why do I see Oscillations in energy using SCF Hartree-Fock Approximation?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, many-body

I have solved Hartree-Fock equations using a self-Consistent method in which I am replacing the Fock coefficients in each iteration with the new calculated coefficients and I am plotting the energy versus iteration.

The problem is that, instead of observing a smooth convergence in energy, I am observing initial decrease in the first few iterations which ends up in oscillations afterwards. It seems the loop is jumping back and forth between two answers. I have tried replacing new Fock coefficients with the previous Fock coefficients plus the average value of (new Fock coefficients+old Fock coefficients) but it did't do any better. (The initial guess is  reasonable)

[image]

Does any one have any idea about other possible ways one can fix the oscillations in HF energy?

Comment: This may be due to the mixing. There are different quantities you can use for the mixing to obtain the input for the next iteration. I don't know which quantity is typically used for Hartree Fock calculations, but I am quite sure that your 50% mixing parameter is very large. Try to mix in only 2% or so of the new coefficients. ...of course, this may also have a very different cause.

Comment: I agree with @GregorMichalicek. This is what [Pulay mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIIS) was introduced to resolve.

Comment: @GregorMichalicek Thank you so much for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are observing is convergence to a two-state limit cycle, a non-linear phenomenon.  Most Hartree Fock iteration schemes involve a non-linear iterated functional mapping and it is not unheard of for such non-linear behavior to occur.  I have observed such behaviior in relativistic Hartree Fock (and Hartree) calculations myself. You are showing the total energy, but if you examine your wave function set you will see similar behavior for the wave functions.

Without knowing details of the specific HF problem you are investigating, it is hard to know what is causing this behavior.  If you are describing the two-particle interaction by a function with a variable parameter, you are likely to see the nature of the non-linear behavior change as you vary your parameter and you may find regions where the behavior goes away entirely.  If you are allowing your wave function quantum numbers to change between inerations, this could be the cause of the problem and restricting yourself to a single set of quantum numbers could fix the problem.  [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226374/non-linear-behavior-of-iterated-functional-maps) is a link to a question that I asked about this behavior on PSE.  I didn't get an answer here, but my question was migrated to Physics Overflow where it did receive a useful response.  [Here](https://www.physicsoverflow.org/34777/non-linear-behavior-of-iterated-functional-maps?show=34844#c34844) is the link to the same question in PO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done the mixing of states (avec+.2 bvec)/1.2 . I also tried other formulas (avec+ (1-iteration/number of iteration) bvec )/(1+Sum((1-iteration/number of iteration)),... but still I am observing oscillation.  The strange thing is that when I am starting with a polarized initial condition, convergence happens, but when I am starting with the random initial condition I see increase in energy (in both cases I still have oscillations).